# Write the first word/letter of each line to a new file

Tags: python, file

I have a file 'master.sql' that contains:

```
a.b.c
d.e.f
g.h.i
```

and I want to write on 'databases.sql' just the first letters, like this:

```
a
d
g
```

Here is my code, but returns just the last letter, the 'g'.

```
with open ('master.sql', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x=(line.split('.')[0]) 


with open('databases.sql', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(x))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you never store `x`, so you get the last value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to write your data as you read it, otherwise you're not going to be able to do what you want. Fortunately, `with` allows you to open multiple files concurrently. This should work for you.

```
with open ('master.sql', 'r') as f1, open('databases.sql', 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        f2.write(line.split('.')[0] + '\n')
```

Don't forget to write a newline, because `file.write` doesn't add one automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using list:

```
x = []

with open('master.sql', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        x.append(line.split('.')[0])

with open('databases.sql', 'w') as f:
    for word in x:
        f.write(str(word)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable x receives all values, but each loop overwrite the last value. Hence, the result is 'g'.

To save all values you can do like this:

```
lst = []
with open ('master.sql', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lst.append(line.split('.')[0])
    x = '\n'.join(lst)

with open('databases.sql', 'w') as f:
    f.write(x)
```